# Acer Win 7 take too long (~15 mins) to hibernate?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, hibernate, acer-aspire

My laptop take too long to hibernate, about 15 mins. But shutdowns and sleep is still quickly. I re-install Win 7 with no help.

After do a simple test, change HDD with another laptop, I detected the issues may be come form the HDD.

How do I fix it? Any suggestion?

Acer 4830, Win 7 64bit, HDD WD Blue 750 Gb, 6GB RAM.

Thanks.

-- update on 25/6 --
After check disk with Crystal Disk Info and face with Windows'alert about hard disk problem, I think it's time to buy new hard disk.

Finally, I bought a new SSD Intel 120GB and using Caddy bay to run both HDD and SSD on may laptop.

Ref here: http://wp.me/p3QcHE-vZ

Thank all.

Comment: Was it always this slow?

Comment: What is the model of your HDD?

Comment: capture a hibernation trace and share it: http://pastebin.com/Y632phPU

Comment: @Karan: it slow down about 3 month to now.

Comment: @i_am_root: WDC WD7500BPVT-22HXZT3

Comment: @magicandre1981: FYI https://www.dropbox.com/s/xnkzav7udety8zc/acer4830-Win7-64bit-cant-hibernate.zip?dl=0

Comment: Writing the data to the HDD is slow. The crystaldisk info report shows that the HDD hs issues and should be replaced. this is the cause of the slow hibernation data writing.

Answer (score 1):

Your laptop has to save up to 6GB of data to disk every time you hibernate, so that is going to take some time definitely. If the slowdown has happened recently you should check your hard drive for errors. Switching to an SSD would be a highly recommended course of action, not just for hibernating quicker but to speed up and improve your general experience too.

Comment: Thank for your work. I had scan HDD with Windows built-in scan dish, check disk with out error. I will plan for SSD.

Comment: Did you do a full `chkdsk /r`? Also check the SMART values for the drive to see if there are any reallocated sectors.

Comment: this is my results, what is it mean and what can i do ? https://www.dropbox.com/s/nz87b8s21514uja/Capture.PNG?dl=0